# Android Toast text on next activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an intent and I want a toast to show as soon as we get to that intent. Code:

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Please enable internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

As you can see im going to the android setting, and I want it to prompt them to activate WiFi. Any ideas or better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather recommend to show a dialog which asks the user to enable the wifi connection for him and then call [`WifiManager.setWifiEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled(boolean)) to switch on wifi.

This way, you don't have to leave your app. It is not possible to show an toast from an external activity.

Answer (score 0):

Quick alternate approach:

Don't show a toast. Display a dialog saying "Please enable internet connection" and when the user presses the "OK" button fire the intent to send him to the settings page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dialog, here's an example

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("WiFi Settings");
    builder.setMessage("Please enable internet connection");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                    // Launch settings activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)););

                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
```